# AWS ALB Ingress has no host address and class is empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

I have followed the AWS official document to create an ALB controller and made sure few things like providing aws region and vpc id when creating a controller.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/alb-ingress.html

However I notice the below error in the ALB contoller pod logs. I am running the controller pods and other resources in Fargate nodes with AKS running on version 1.21.0

> {"level":"error","ts":1643650856.9675832,"logger":"controller-runtime.manager.controller.ingress","msg":"Reconciler error","name":"app-ingress","namespace":"backend","error":"WebIdentityErr: failed to retrieve credentials\ncaused by: RequestError: send request failed\ncaused by: Post "https://sts.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/": dial tcp: i/o timeout"}

Comment: I have found similar error. It is under [this link](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/issues/1360). Could you try to configure coreDNS to run on fargate ([documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/fargate-getting-started.html))?

Comment: Thanks @kkopczak that was the issue for the ingress. It got resolved after I executed the commands in the section Update CoreDNS. However now I have a different issue. The Ingress loadbalancer target group is just empty.

Comment: I have added an answer. Consider adding your next issue to the new question on the StackOverflow for clearness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your error it looks like your coreDNS setup is not correct.

> By default, CoreDNS is configured to run on Amazon EC2 infrastructure on Amazon EKS clusters. If you want to *only* run your pods on Fargate in your cluster, complete the following steps.

1. Create a Fargate profile for CoreDNS.

```
aws eks create-fargate-profile \
    --fargate-profile-name coredns \
    --cluster-name [your cluster name] \
    --pod-execution-role-arn arn:aws:iam::[your account ID]:role/AmazonEKSFargatePodExecutionRole \
    --selectors namespace=kube-system,labels={k8s-app=kube-dns} \
    --subnets subnet-[1st ID of your private subnet] subnet-[2nd ID of your private subnet] subnet-[3rd ID of your private subnet]
```

Replace `AmazonEKSFargatePodExecutionRole` with the name of your pod execution role. If you don't have a pod execution role, you must [create one](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/fargate-getting-started.html#fargate-sg-pod-execution-role) first.

> **NOTE**
> The format of the role ARN must be `` arn:aws:iam::`111122223333`:role/`role-name` `` .

2. Following command removes the `eks.amazonaws.com/compute-type : ec2` annotation from the CoreDNS pods, run it:

```yaml
kubectl patch deployment coredns \
    -n kube-system \
    --type json \
    -p='[{"op": "remove", "path": "/spec/template/metadata/annotations/eks.amazonaws.com~1compute-type"}]'
```

[Here is a link to the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/fargate-getting-started.html).